# Couchbase modify meta data experation using Spring

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, couchbase

When using Spring Couchbase connector I can easily get version for optimistic locking by having this in my class:

```
public class MyClass {

    @Version
    private String version;

    .... rest of class omitted ....

}
```

I'm now trying to find a similar way to get and be able to modify the meta data for expiration. I'm unable to find how to do this.

Can someone please give an example? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With spring data couchbase library (until the latest Version 3.0.8.RELEASE), document expiry can be defined by using `@Document(expiry = 10)` or `@Document(expiryExpression = "${valid.document.expiry}")` on the class. There is also an optional boolean attribute `touchOnRead` which needs to be added with `@Document`, which would reset the expiry timer whenever the document is directly read. Please note that currently the expiry of an existing document cannot be read/modified directly with this library. One way would be to access the below APIs exposed by Couchbase's own java SDK (com.couchbase.client.java)

- `getAndTouch` - allows you to retrieve a document while modifying its expiration time
- `touch` - allows you to modify a document’s expiration time without otherwise accessing the document

You can find the method signatures of the above two here : http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-java-client-2.2.4/com/couchbase/client/java/Bucket.html

The above two APIs can be accessed via the spring data couchbase library as follows

```
 couchbaseTemplate.getCouchbaseBucket().touch(...)
 couchbaseTemplate.getCouchbaseBucket().getAndTouch(...)
```

The `getCouchbaseBucket()` method of the spring library returns a reference to `com.couchbase.client.java.Bucket` using which the `touch` and `getAndTouch` methods can be used.

Comment: Hi Madhu, thanks for your answer. I am aware of doing it this way but this does not allow us to change the expiry at run time. Some docs we may want to keep for 6 months, others 9 months or a year. These options do not give us the ability to control it at run time. That is why we are looking for a way to get the value as variable in the class.

Comment: @DavidR see if you can use CouchbaseDocument class somehow, since it exposes getter and setter for ExpirationTime. Check this https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/couchbase/core/mapping/CouchbaseDocument.html

Comment: Using CouchbaseDocument looked promising and we gave it a shot. Unfortunately our test shows it creates an expiration value in the document (which doesn't work) and does not actually update the meta data expiration value. Honestly, that seems like a bug to me but not sure.

Comment: @DavidR Ah that's a bummer. But wouldn't `couchbaseTemplate.getCouchbaseBucket().touch(...)` work for you? As you can dynamically set the expiry of the document using the same.